# Ir a una pagina en un controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla User con una variable llamada rol, para la cual tengo este formulario:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

@Logged()
@include('partials.errors')
<form method="POST" action="../puesto">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rol" class="col-md-12 control-label"> <h2>{{ __("rol elegido") }}</h2>
        </label>
        <input name="rol" type="radio" value="administrador">   Administrador<br>
        <input checked="checked" name="rol" type="radio" value="cliente">   Cliente
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="addrol" class="btn btn-default"> {{ __("Ingresar rol") }}
    </button>
</form>
@else
<h1 class="text-center text-mute" style="color:#FF0000"> {{ __("¡DEJA DE HACER EL INDIO Y INICIA SESIÓN!") }} </h1>
@endLogged
@endsection
```

Una vez que se efectua el formulario vamos a este codigo en web.php:

```
Route::post('/puesto','UserController@acto');
```

Lo cual me lleva a lo siguiente:

```
public function acto(Request $request){
        $normas=[
            'rol' => 'required',
        ];

        $this->validate($request,$normas);

        Auth::user()->rol=$request->rol;
        Auth::user()->save();
        return back()->with('message', ['success', __("Rol seleccionado correctamente.")]);
    }
```

El return del final me devolvera al formulario, pero no me interesa eso, sino que quiero que me lleve a la pagina principal (***Route::get('/', 'PlantasController@index'***);).

He probado 2 back() pero da error. Tambien he probado poner 'return view(vegetal.index)' pero da error. ¿Como lo logro?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he arreglado.
Era cuestión de sustituir el return->back() por este codigo:

```
return redirect('/')->with('message', ['success', __("Rol seleccionado correctamente.")]);
```

Comment: Me alegra que lo solucionaras. Intenta, si puedes, mejorar la respuesta con más explicación para futuros users siguiendo [answer]. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

En Laravel es considerada una mála práctica utilizar rutas (url) en el código directamente, para eso existen los archivos de rutas (web.php, api.php, etc...).

Lo recomendado es apuntar al "nombre" de una ruta o incluso al controlador:

En vez de:

```
<form method="POST" action="../puesto">
```

Debería ser algo como:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('user.bla') }}">
```

Y en routes\web.php se define algo así:

```
Route::post('puesto', 'UserController@acto')->name('user.bla');
```

---

En cuanto a la redirección, sería algo así:

```
Route::get('/', 'PlantasController@index')->name('home');
```

y la redirección sería de esta manera:

```
return redirect()->route('home')->with('message', ....);
```

---

¿Cuál es la diferencia con lo que usas ahora?

Que si por algún motivo cambian las url, no tienes que hacer una búsqueda de dichos valores por todo el código de la aplicación.